# tools:RGUI disappears from globalenv R

Tags: r

I just installed the newest version of R for my OS -- R version 3.1.3 for MAC. The tools:RGUI does not load properly. Half the time, I open R and search() does not include tools:RGUI. The other half of the time, it does appear but then quickly disappears from the global environment. As a result, I cannot use the help function or search for and install packages. My internet connection is fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd try to remove and reinstall the whole thing first to see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the problem; I had detach() at the start of my code. I do not normally attach data as I have been told it is a bad habit that can lead to problems. They were right. I have deleted all the references to attach and detach and things seem to work fine now.